# Conditional Probability vs Multiplication Rule

Tags: probability

I am not clear about the differences between the conditional probability and the multiplication rule. Both these consist of a probability conditioned to another event(s).  Also, though I thought that the sample space changes only in the case  of conditional probability, here is an example where the sample space changes for the multiplication rule as well. Say, a bag contains 10 identical balls, of which 4 are blue and 6 are red. If 2 balls are drawn at random, the probability of both of them being red is (6/10)*(5/9). Here, the multiplication rule was used and the sample space was altered to 9. Please clear these concepts by using examples for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*multiplication rule*](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/multiplication-rule-of-probability) is practicized if we are dealing with two *independent* events and this by calculation of the probability of their intersection:$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$

Dealing with two events that are not necessarily independent we can still find $P(A\cap B)$ by means of a multiplication but this time it is the rule:$$P(A\cap B)=P(A\mid B)P(B)$$

Labeling this also as "multiplication rule" might cause confusion and IMHO must be avoided.

---

**edit (rectification):**

I am convinced now (see comment of Michael, and my answer on that) that the muliplication rule is the general rule that: $$P(A\cap B)=P(A\mid B)P(B)$$ which in the *special case* that $A$ and $B$ are independent simplifies to: $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$
Feel free to unaccept in order to accept another answer to your question.

Comment: That does makes sense, thank you. Could you also, using examples, explain in a non-mathematical way what independent events are?

Comment: In mathematical way two events are independent iff $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$. It can be interpreted as the fact that the occurence of $B$ will have no effect on the probability that event $A$ will occur (and vice versa). In conditional terms: $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$. So in that case the two rules mentioned in my answer coincide.

Comment: @drhab : Why would it lead to confusion? It is a commonplace usage.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I always thought (not anymore) that the term was only used for independent events. Now I am converted. This after some googling and also your comment.  Further there was confusion by the OP which made me say "might cause confusion".

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The "multiplication rule" is a rule involving conditional probabilities:
\begin{align}
& \Pr(A\ \&\ B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B\mid A) \\
& \Pr(A\ \&\ B) = \Pr(B)\Pr(A\mid B)
\end{align}

> the sample space changes only in the case of conditional probability,

That is correct.

> here is an example where the sample space changes for the multiplication rule as well. Say, a bag contains 10 identical balls, of which 4 are blue and 6 are red. If 2 balls are drawn at random, the probability of both of them being red is $(6/10)\times(5/9).$ Here, the multiplication rule was used and the sample space was altered to $9.$

The sample space was altered because a conditional probability was used:

$$
\Pr(\text{both are red}) = \Pr(\text{1st is red}) \cdot \Pr(\text{2nd is red}\mid \text{1st is red}) = \frac 6 {10} \times \frac 5 9.
$$

Comment: So what exactly is the difference between these two rules?

Comment: @RayyanAsifKhan : I don't see two rules here; I see only one: the multiplication rule.